# How to stop an animation

Tags: android, animation

I have created an animation (by below Code) of a bouncing ball.

I wanted to know how to stop this animation on a particular condition, like after 10 seconds or when the ball reaches at particular coordinates.

The code:

```
public class MyDemoView extends ImageView{
    private Context mContext;

    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    private int xVelocity = 10;
    private int yVelocity = 5;
    private Handler h;
    private final int FRAME_RATE = 30;

    public MyDemoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        h = new Handler();
    }

    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate();
         }
    };

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);

        if (x<0 && y <0) {
            x = this.getWidth()/2;
            y = this.getHeight()/2;
        } else {
            x += xVelocity;
            y += yVelocity;

            if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
                xVelocity = xVelocity*-1;
            }

            if ((y > this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) || (y < 0)) {
                yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
            }
        }

        c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x2, y2, null);
        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop animation use the code below:

```
object.clearAnimation();
```

or

```
animation.cancel();
```

The latter may not work for 2.1, can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code , simply call `h.removeCallbacks(r)` ?